# Basis & dimensions of polynomials in x and y?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following homework problem, and I just want to clarify if I completed it correctly since it's been a while since I've taken linear algebra.

Let V be the space of polynomials in $ x$ and $y$ of degree $\leq 10$. Specify a basis of V and compute $dim V$.

Basis: $[{1, x, y, x^2, y^2, x^3, y^3, x^4,y^4, x^5, y^5,x^6, y^6, x^7, y^7, x^8, y^8, x^9, y^9, x^{10}, y^{10}}]$

$ dim V = 21 $. The dimension is simply the number of elements, correct?

Is this correct?

Comment: How do you express $xy$ in that basis?

Comment: @badjohn Would I have to multiply each term, such as $ x^3 y^4$? Should I also include 0 as a part of the basis?

Comment: You may need to check what is intended but I would expect that forms such as $x^m y^n$ would be included.  If so, I would expect the dimension to be $121$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to express, say, $xy$ as a linear combination of the elements in the basis you suggested, so it is incorrect. The correct basis is $B=\{ x^ny^m\mid n+m\leq 10\}$, implying that the space has dimension $66$.

Proving that it is spanning and linearly independent is a simple exercise.

Comment: We have interpreted degree $10$ differently..  I took it that the degree of $x$ or $y$ may be $10$.   You took it that the sum must be $10$.  Either way, $xy$ is independent of $x$ and $y$..

Comment: The space dimension is actually 66 and not 55, as the other answerer shows. In general the space of polynomials of degree $n$ with domain a subset of the plane is $\frac{n+2}{2}(n+1)$ and not $\frac{n+1}{2}n$, or equivalently ${n+2\choose 2}$

Comment: @MehdiSlimani I think you're right. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question from this very abstract (but rewarding) textbook.

I think it comes down to how you interpret "polynomials in x and y of degree ≤ 10." I can't think of an especially compelling case for interpreting it as x and y are independently up to degree 10 (as user badjohn commented) or if their combined degree must be ≤ 10.

My final answer ended up being:

$$
B = \{x^ky^p: k + p = n, n ≤10, k\in \mathbb{N}^0, p\in \mathbb{N}^0\}
$$

So the basis consists of $${x^{10}y^{0},x^9y, x^9y^0, x^8y^2, x^8y^1, x^8y^0, x^7y^3, ..., x^1y^9,..., x^0y^{10}, x^0y^9, ..., x^0y^1, 1}  $$

In other words, there are 11 terms that start with $$x^0,$$

10 terms that start with $$ x^1. $$

So dim(B) can be generalized as

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{10}(11-n)=66,$$

which is the triangle number of 11.